# Notify the Client when a pdf file gets saved on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm Building a .Net MVC app and was wondering what the approach would be to have the server notify the front-end when ever a pdf file is saved into a specific directory.

There is a process that runs and generates the PDFs which are then sent to a directory on the server. When ever that directory is updated I would like the server to push a notification to the front-end. I'm not sure what classes/namespaces are available in .Net to aid in such a thing though. Just looking for a little guidance, Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean Asynchronous transfer notification?

Answer (score 3):

A good option is SignalR.

> SignalR is a library for ASP.NET developers that simplifies the process of adding real-time web functionality to applications. Real-time web functionality is the ability to have server code push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes available, rather than having the server wait for a client to request new data.

[Introduction to SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

To monitor events on the filesystem you can use the [FileSystemWatcher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) which can monitor folderwide events.

Comment: I have actually been looking into SignalR a lot. My main issues is I'm not sure how to handle dealing with the file system using C# in order to check if a pdf exists in a folder.

Comment: hmm looks like System.IO could make be a possible option.

Comment: you can make a table in database containing the path of file and file creation date and by whom user was uploaded then by using signalR you can notify the client